# Is the soul tied and can one break that tie?

Tags: soul

I have heard that the soul is tied to your wife or husband, but if so, can you break off that "soul-tie" ?

Comment: Why do you end all your questions with ~"what does the Talmud or Torah say about this question?"? This is a Judaism site. By default, pretty much every question seeks to know what sources in Judaism (i.e. the Torah, in the most general sense) say about the question. By adding that postscript, you seem to be restricting answers to those sourced only in the Torah (hence presumably some more limited meaning of that term, most likely the Pentateuch) and/or Talmud, without explaining *why* you'd restrict thus. It's a very strange restriction.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of the "besheret", literally destiny, but understood to be analogous to soulmate. There is Jewish imagery which indicates that each man and woman were created as one entity metaphorically joined at the back, which was separated and brought into this world with the purpose of joining back together. This is purported to be based off making Genesis 1:27 mesh with the Adam and Eve narrative, though the idea is first documented in Plato's Symposium in a speech given by Aristophanes.

There are talmudic and midrashic examples of the idea that G-d is the one who is responsible for matches. (e.g. Genesis Rabba 68:3-4, Sotah 2a, Sanhedrin 22a) However, this is not so strong as a soulmate. G-d could very well have reasons for setting up an unsuccessful marriage that is beyond our wisdom. Also, this does not mean we must go through with G-d's plans. This would be a violation of freewill. The Rambam rejects the idea of soulmates in Shemoneh Perakim 8

> [There is no contradiction to this from the following] statement of our Sages: “Everything is in the hands of heaven except the fear of heaven.” This statement is true and conforms to the conceptual framework that we have explained. Nevertheless, many people err with regard to it and imagine that a person is fated with regard to many of the matters in which he is given free choice: e.g., whether he will marry a particular woman or acquire a sum of money through theft.
>
> This is absolutely not true. For if a person marries a woman, granting her a marriage contract and performing the rites of kiddushin, he is performing a mitzvah, and God does not decree that we will perform any mitzvot. Should the marriage be forbidden, [entering into it] is a sin, and God does not decree that we will perform any sins.

The idea of a soulmate is also undermined by the laws concerning divorce. Divorce, while not considered ideal, is not considered to be wrong for forbidden such is the case in other religions. If G-d was in the business of forming unbreakable soul bonds, he would not have revealed ways to break said bonds.

Comment: “The soul of Jonathan was knit with the soul of David, and Jonathan loved him as his own soul” ...(1 Samuel 18:1 KJV).Not a couple but,but seems like somekinda soul- tie but in friendship.

Comment: @Eagel you asked about wives and husbands.  If you meant to ask about non-marital connections you should have done so.  (*Do not edit to do that now*, as this answer already exists and is upvoted.)  If you take a little more time and care in asking your questions you can avoid some of these issues.

Comment: I did just add a comment

Comment: @Eagel Don't read it too literally. The word for knit used there also means alliance, and the word for soul there has many meanings. Here the best translation would be "Jonathan's intentions aligned with David's intentions."